# Verifying that setter was called on mocked object with Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test

Given the following service method in a Spring Boot application:

```java
@Transactional
public void updateCategory(long categoryId, CategoryData categoryData) {
  final Category category = categoryRepository.findById(categoryId).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
  category.setName(categoryData.getName());
}
```

I know how to instruct Mockito to mock the `categoryRepository.findById()` result.

However, I couldn't figure out yet: Is it possible to verify that `category.setName()`  was called with the exact argument of `categoryData.getName()`?

Comment: During the test, is the `category` here a real model object or a Mockito-created mock? Are you familiar with Mockito's [`verify`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1) command?

Comment: The `category` here is an object returned by `Mockito.when()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `Mockito.verify`, and a test looking like:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CategoryServiceTest {
    @Mock
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    CategoryService categoryService;

    @Test
    public void testUpdateCategoryMarksEntityDirty() {
        // given
        long categoryId = 1L;
        Category category = mock(Category.class);
        String newCategoryName = "NewCategoryName";
        when(categoryRepository.findById(categoryId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(category));

        // when
        categoryService.updateCategory(categoryId, new CategoryData(newCategoryName));

        // then
        verify(category, times(1)).setName(newCategoryName);
    }
}
```

I must, however, advise against this style of testing.

Your code suggests that you are using a DB Access library with dirty-checking mechanism (JPA / Hibernate?). Your test focuses on the details of interaction with your DB Access layer, instead of business requirement - the update is successfully saved in the DB.

Thus, I would opt for a test against a real db, with following steps:

- given: insert a Category into your DB
- when: CategoryService.update is called
- then: subsequent calls to categoryRepository.findById return updated entity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I agree on your advice and I'm aware of the issue. The point is, we don't have a reliable integration test setup yet. Once this is in place, I'd like to refactor this test anyway :-)

Comment: I would think of launching a db on docker - Testcontainers is a good tool to do that